# Should I use a server-side script or a web service?

Tags: web-services

I need to be able to access a mySQL database from my iPhone, for both read and write ops.  Instead of using MCPKit (due to security and speed considerations), I'd like to access the db through a separate service.  The app is iPhone SDK, so I need to get data back in XML form, not as a web page.

I am trying to decide whether to write a Java web service (SOAP) to provide this link, or to just throw together a PHP script on the server side.  I can create either solution, but I don't know enough to figure out the advantages/disadvantages of the choice.  Please help; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing both the client and the server, and performance isn't a significant issue, then the primary remaining consideration is development time.

So, what tools do you have at your disposal? Which platform will allow you to do this with the least amount of work? If it's a toss-up between the two, then pick the one you're most familiar with.

Comment: Thanks tylerl! I realize that the path of least resistance is probably best, which for me means a php script.  I'm trying to understand how this decision affects performance, extensibility, reliability... I guess I'm trying to understand when you'd use one and not the other, and why. Thanks again!

Comment: Standards (such as SOAP) are primarily useful for interoperability. If you control both ends, then suddenly that doesn't matter as much. As long as your method works, it work.